# QtCreator error: QMYSQL driver not loaded

Tags: mysql, sql, database, qt, qt-creator

When I try to access mysql I get the following error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3
```

I have installed mysql in C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL.

I googled this problem and i was given this link: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45295-using-mysql-plugin

however, I cant locate any of the files that inbush was talking about. I get lost starting here:

> For ease of execution of commands in a terminal to a system variable
>   Path: "C: \ Qt \ 2010.05 \ qt \ bin \; C: \ Qt \ 2010.05 \ mingw \ bin
>   \". These directories are executable files qmake, mingw32make, g + +.
>   REBOOT.
>
> In the terminal, go to QTDIR / src / plugins / sqldrivers / mysql (cd
>   C: \ Qt \ 2010.05 \ qt \ src \ plugins \ sqldrivers \ mysql)
>
> Perform qmake-o Makefile "INCLUDEPATH + = C: / MySQL / include" "LIBS
>   + = C: / MySQL / lib / opt / libmysql.lib" mysql.pro

Location of my Qt files etc:

Compiler:
http://puu.sh/3mdR0.png

Actual Qt:
http://puu.sh/3mdSA.png

Please help.

Comment: You probably only have a binary package of Qt, to compile the MySQL driver you need the Qt sources.

Comment: I can't seem to find the sources for vs2010, only minGW...

Comment: There's only one Qt source package containing the source used for all platforms and compilers. For 5.0.2 that is http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2.zip (also available as tar.gz)

Comment: so i downloaded the qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.2.zip, extrated qtbase? into my Qt directory, and installed perl64, and all the lines work except for "Perform mingw32-make" from http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/45295-using-mysql-plugin

Comment: i am using msvc2010 compiler and not mingw32

Comment: that'd be "nmake" then

Comment: i get this error when i try to nmake http://puu.sh/3mOXS.png

Comment: you have to use MSVC's dos prompt entry in the start menu or source the vcvarsall.bat (or similar) coming with MSVC.

Comment: this is what i did: http://puu.sh/3nyG9.png however, it still does not work :(. Is there anyway that you can help me get this sorted sooner? It's taking quite some time. Sorry for being so bad at this..

Answer (score 0):

if @FrankOsterfeld is right, http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#supported-databases should help

Answer (score 0):

I may be a few years too late, but this is how I got it working in windows.
Add the  following line in the .pro file.(Modify the path to fit your MySQL)

```
LIBS += -L"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\lib" -llibmysql
```